# Firebase reading ordered data reversed order?

Tags: firebase

I have an ordered list of firebase locations. I'm using a property `ut` (update time) as their priority. I want to make the list such that it's easy to get the latest updated documents.

So I set the priority to be negative `ut`.

```
var query = fb.child('view/documents').limit(20)
query.on('child_added', function(child) { 
  console.log(child.val())
  console.log(child.getPriority())
})
```

I expect something like this to return the latest 20 documents, but it doesn't, it returns the oldest 20. In the forge I see the listing the way I expect it, the latest documents are on top, but the query is sending me the bottom 20. It seems contrary to my expectations for the query to send me the bottom 20 instead of the top 20.

What really confuses me is that the child_added returns the expected order, latest (smallest priority) first. But again it's the oldest in the list.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in firebase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is : .startAt()
before the limit(), that will return the data in correct order, without the keyword you will always get the last specified number of children.

Here is the reference : https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/query/limit.html

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion, but that's really how it's supposed to work: `limit(20)` returns the 20 greatest-priority children, starting with the 20th-greatest-priority child and ending with the absolute-greatest-priority child (and then updating whenever a new child is added whose priority is great enough to make the list).

You can see the example at https://www.firebase.com/docs/queries.html, where the priority is the Unix timestamp of when the message was sent, and `messageListRef.limit(100)` is used to get the 100 most recent messages (i.e., the 100 greatest-priority messages).